# Influence of protic and aprotic solvents on SN reactions

Tags: reaction-mechanism

How does protic and aprotic solvents influence reaction mechanism considering SN1 vs SN2?

Comment: You will find your answer [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/06/18/what-makes-a-good-nucleophile/) and [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/08/08/comparing-the-sn1-and-sn2-reactions/)

Answer (score 3):

As you know, $\mathrm{S_N1}$ and $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reactions have different mechanisms. $\mathrm{S_N1}$ occurs in 2 steps: formation of a carbocation and addition of the nucleophile. However, $\mathrm{S_N2}$ has a one-step mechanism where the addition of the nucleophile and the elimination of the leaving group happen simultaneously.

A protic solvent would participate in hydrogen bonding with the nucleophile since it can easily share one proton. A solvent shell is thus formed around the nucleophile, making him less able to undergo a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction.

Comment: I believe that a protic solvent also helps stabilise the carbocation in a Sn1 mechanism due to the dipole interactions.